# markdown indentation (github)

Tags: github, indentation, github-flavored-markdown

When I write the code below, I can see the indentation in HackMD. But I can't see the same effect in GitHub.  What can I do to solve it?

```html
<style>
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: 2em;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub [doesn't allow arbitrary styles in its Markdown](https://github.com/github/markup/tree/master#github-markup):

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes. See the [sanitization filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) for the full whitelist.

You're probably going to have to live with its default rendering.